# Keyboard not appearing?

Tags: xcode, ios-simulator

In the iPhone SE simulator a keyboard does not appear. I was watching a video and the guy was teaching me how to toggle it. There is nothing to toggle. It changed nothing adding code. Anyone know how to fix this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to enable the software keyboard in the Simulator. Normally, you would just use your computer's keyboard as input.

[image]